# SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use the simple sendemail script below:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var startColumn = 1;  // First column of data to process
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var Column = data[i];
    var subject = Column[0]        // 1st column
    var emailAddress = "somemail@somemail.com";  // 2nd column
    var message = Column[2];       // 3rd column
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 10, file "Code")

sheet is returning null and I don't understand why. I have a spreadsheet up and saved on one of my tabs so I don't understand why it would return null. Any ideas or debugging tricks to find out why?

Thanks,
Mason

Comment: Tried the code and it works as planned.

Comment: The `getRange` you're using is retrieving only one cell. Better is to use `var data = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, 1, 3).getValues()`

Answer (score 5):

I have a project that calls this method via API. I suspect that because of that, there is no 'active sheet' and therefore it returns null.

I was able to work around this by getting the sheet via ID:

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<SHEET-ID>").getActiveSheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` doesn't seems to work always.  you can try using `SpreadsheetApp.openById` method instead.

If you would like get the first sheet from multi-spreadsheet, then you can try,

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet_id").getSheets()[0];
```

Refer following link for more info.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid